# Memory allocation for a struct in go

Tags: go, memory, 64-bit

I recently came across http://golang-sizeof.tips/ which explains how the memory is allocated for a struct. I get it that to ensure contiguous memory allocation, we add padding when allocating memory for variables which without padding will not get contiguous memory. So i was testing out various combinations on my 64-bit computer, and found a mismatch between the results on the site and my computer. It was for this case:

```
type S2 struct {
    a string
    b bool
    e bool
    d int32
    f bool
    c string
}
```

In the main, the following code gives me `48` as the size of the variable.

```
y := S2{"q", true, true,2,true,"w"}
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(y))
```

But this is different from what its supposed to be as per [http://golang-sizeof.tips/?t=blahblah](http://golang-sizeof.tips/?t=c3RydWN0IHsKCWEgc3RyaW5nCgliIGJvb2wKCWUgYm9vbAoJZCBpbnQzMgoJZiBib29sCgljIHN0cmluZwp9Cg==). Why is this kind of behaviour observed? (I hope this is not some problem with my computer alone). 
Edit: Logically speaking padding is not necessary in between fields `d` and `f`

I also ran the following code just to make sure.

```
fmt.Println(unsafe.Offsetof(y.a))
fmt.Println(unsafe.Offsetof(y.b))
fmt.Println(unsafe.Offsetof(y.e))
fmt.Println(unsafe.Offsetof(y.d))
fmt.Println(unsafe.Offsetof(y.f))
fmt.Println(unsafe.Offsetof(y.c))
```

Result:

```
0
16
17
20
24
32
```

[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org) uses 32-bit machine, so i doubt that the same can be reproduced there!

Comment: That site is wrong. Not sure why you would question the actual implementation over some unofficial website.

Comment: You'd have to ask whoever runs that site why it's wrong.

Comment: But logically it doesn't make sense to have padding in between fields `d` and `f`

Comment: @NannanAV: why doesn't it make sense? The alignment guarantee of the `int32` is 4, so it can't start on byte 18.

Comment: bytes 16 to 23 are contiguous on a 64bit machine, hence it can!

Comment: @NannanAV No it can't. Some things do have strict and sensible alignment requirements and you cannot and especially you _do_ _no_ _want_ to missalign your data because accessing missalined data is 10x slower.

Comment: If you're refuting the actual implementation, you need a strong thesis and _explanation_. Saying "it's contiguous" doesn't explain _why_ you think it's sufficient. If the alignment guarantee is 4 for int32, then it cannot have an offset of 18 simply because it's not a multiple of 4.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation of 48 bytes is correct for amd64.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type S2 struct { // align 16
    a string // size 16 = 8 + 8
    b bool   // size 1
    e bool   // size 1
    // pad size 2
    d int32 // size 4
    f bool  // size 1
    // pad size 7
    c string // size 16 = 8 + 8
}

func main() {
    y := S2{}
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(y))

    fmt.Println(unsafe.Offsetof(y.a))
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Offsetof(y.b))
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Offsetof(y.e))
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Offsetof(y.d))
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Offsetof(y.f))
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Offsetof(y.c))

    fmt.Println(&y.a)
    fmt.Println(&y.b)
    fmt.Println(&y.e)
    fmt.Println(&y.d)
    fmt.Println(&y.f)
    fmt.Println(&y.c)
}
```

Output:

```
48
0
16
17
20
24
32
0xc000070150
0xc000070160
0xc000070161
0xc000070164
0xc000070168
0xc000070170
```

---

[The Go Programming Language Specification : Size and alignment guarantees](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees)

Comment: refer comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540575/memory-allocation-for-a-struct-in-go#comment90050152_51540575

Comment: @NannanAV: Your math doesn't make sense. It's wrong.